# Forward Path for each vertex

Tags: c++, graph, depth-first-search

A **forward path** from vertex v is a path that ends in a sink node. Write an O(n) algorithm to detect number of forward path for each vertex.

**The logic I can think of**

I created an array with the total number of vertexes and initialized them o zero.

Right before the DFS explore, I tried to write

```
 if(v has no outgoing edge)
       forwardPath[v] += 1
```

However, I am not really sure how I can implement the if statement.

**What I did**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

// Graph class represents a directed graph
// using adjacency list representation
static int *forwardPath;
class Graph
{
public:
    int V;    // No. of vertices

    // Pointer to an array containing
    // adjacency lists
    list<int> *adj;

    // A recursive function used by DFS
    void DFSUtil(int v, bool visited[]);
public:
    Graph(int V);   // Constructor

    // function to add an edge to graph
    void addEdge(int v, int w);

    // DFS traversal of the vertices
    // reachable from v
    void DFS(int v);

    void printGraph(int V);
};

Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<int>[V];
    forwardPath = new int[V];
    for(int i=0; i<V; i++){
        forwardPath[i] = 0;
    }
}

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
    adj[v].push_back(w); // Add w to v’s list.
}

void Graph::DFSUtil(int v, bool visited[])
{
    // Mark the current node as visited and
    // print it

    visited[v] = true;

    cout << v << " ";

    // Recur for all the vertices adjacent
    // to this vertex
    list<int>::iterator i;
    for (i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
        if (!visited[*i]){
            forwardPath[v] += 1;
            DFSUtil(*i, visited);
        }
}

// DFS traversal of the vertices reachable from v.
// It uses recursive DFSUtil()
void Graph::DFS(int v)
{
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited
    bool *visited = new bool[V];
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        visited[i] = false;

    // Call the recursive helper function
    // to print DFS traversal
    DFSUtil(v, visited);
}

void printForwardPath(){
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout<<forwardPath[i]<< " ";
    }

    cout<<endl;
}

void Graph:: printGraph(int V){
    list<int> :: iterator it;
    for(int i=0; i<V; i++){
        cout<<i <<"-->";
        for(int node:adj[i])
            cout<<node<<",";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

// Driver code
int main()
{
    // Create a graph given in the above diagram
    Graph g(6);
    g.addEdge(0, 1);
    g.addEdge(0, 2);
    g.addEdge(2, 3);
    g.addEdge(2, 5);
    g.addEdge(3, 4);

    g.printGraph(6);

    cout<<"BELOW IS DFS "<<endl;

    cout<<endl;

    cout << "Following is Depth First Traversal"
            " (starting from vertex 0) \n";
    g.DFS(0);
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"**********"<<endl;

    cout << "Number of forward path\n"
            "in the graph \n";

    printForwardPath();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `adj = new list<int>[V];` is a bad idea. You almost never want to dynamically allocate a `list` or any other library container. They exist in large part to eliminate the need for such memory management. Automatically allocate the `list` and let it handle things as you add and remove items. Similarly there is no need for `forwardPath = new int[V];` when `std::vector` is available. forwardPath as a global variable is a bad idea as well. You can only safely have one `Graph` if it's global. This should probably be a local `vector` returned from the function that computes the path.

Comment: Answer the question "How do you distinguish an inbound edge from an outbound edge?" and you'll have your solution.

Comment: `bool *visited = new bool[V];` -- Memory leak.  You could have just used `std::vector<bool> visited(V)`;